# python check if type is serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, cloudpickle

Trying to use a distributed cluster computing framework, i want to pre-validate a graph before running it for non serializable types.

Presume i have the following class:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I know that the class/type Human is a serializable type, but how could i check that in code without needing an instance of that type? In contrast how can i know when a type (like a DbConnection) is not serializable?

I tried a combination of inspect.signature, typings.getargs, typings.getorigin such that i could get the object signature, but i cannot whitelist/blacklist all possible types. I also expect that looking just at an object signature is not enough to determine if an object is serializable

Comment: *"how can i know when a type […] is not serializable?"* It raises an exception if you try.

Comment: Hey @KlausD. - probably the question was not clear enough, but i would like to make the check without having an instance. I would like to know if i could somehow infer from the type alone if smth is serializable

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [How to check if an object is pickleable](/q/17872056/4518341). I don't know `pickle` that well but I googled "python check if type is pickleable" (pretty much what you wrote as the title) and found this, which looks promising.